# Quicksort sorts all but a few items

Tags: java, quicksort

I have spent a lot of time attempting to figure out what I don't have right; debugging and all but I just cannot seem to put my finger on why my quicksort misses a few items of sorting.

I've copied my code for sort and partition below. I have a feeling it's something extremely obvious I am over looking but I have spent endless hours debugging, researching, and rewriting my code and it always turns out the same.

```
// quicksort the subarray from a[lo] to a[hi]
private void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    if((hi-lo)>1){
        int pivot = partition(a,lo,hi);
        sort(a,lo,pivot);
        sort(a,pivot+1,hi);
    }
}

// partition the subarray a[lo .. hi] by returning an index j
// so that a[lo .. j-1] <= a[j] <= a[j+1 .. hi]
private int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    //find middle
    int pivotIndex = (hi+lo)/2;
    //pick pivot
    Comparable pivot = a[pivotIndex];
    //create left and right pointers
    int left = lo, right = hi;
    //start comparing
    //compare until left passes right
    while(left<right){
        //while left is less than pivot move on
        while(a[left].compareTo(pivot) < 0) left++;
        //while right is greater than pivot move on
        while(a[right].compareTo(pivot) > 0) right--;
        //if the pointers have passed each other we're done
        //if a[left] is greater than a[right] swap them
        if(a[left].compareTo(a[right]) > 0){
            Comparable holder = a[left];
            a[left] = a[right];
            a[right] = holder;
            //increment/decrement
            left++; right--;
        }
    }
    return right;
}
```

Comment: @GrzegorzKaczan pretty sure it's not. retagged to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `left++; right--;` and everything should be fine.

Comment: I haven't found the bug yet myself, but I ran a test case sorting `Character[] s = {'z','y','x','a','b','c','w','v','u'};` and removing the `left++; right--;` did not correct the problem.

Comment: Pretty strange.. I thought a little bit about it again, and I guess something about the recursive calls goes wrong. But I'm not able to see the fault directly.
Just take a look at the implementations of http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html (which is pretty similar to yours) but does the recursion more or less inside the partitioning part.